# Does ServerAlias config under apache accepts something like "www.example.com/somthing/more"?

Tags: apache-2.2, serveralias

I want to add a ServerAlias pointing to a url say "www.example.com/somthing/more". I know this is perfectly possible in case of "www.example.com" or "*.example.com" for eg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

No.

---

`Server[Name|Alias]` accepts hostnames only.

To go beyond hostnames, you need to look into `<Location>`, `Alias`, `Rewrite` directives or the like.

If you had `foo.example.com` and wanted to redirect to `http://bar.example.com/directory`, then you could do something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo.example.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* http://bar.example.com/directory [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```